# Append parameter in url to make search filter

Tags: php, jquery, html

hi I want to rewrite url parameters values on checkbox click,
similar to amazon search. filter
[image]
 i try this code

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript1.2">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function (e) {
  var seasoning = '', tempArray = [];
  $('input[name="vegetables[]"]:checked').each(function(){
      tempArray.push($(this).val());
  })
  if(tempArray.length !== 0){
     seasoning+='vegetables='+tempArray.toString();
     tempArray = [];
  }
  
  $('input[name="seasoning[]"]:checked').each(function(){
      tempArray.push($(this).val());
  })
  if(tempArray.length !== 0){
     seasoning+='&seasoning='+tempArray.toString();
  }
 
 //window.location ='http://localhost/sss.php?'+seasoning;
console.log('http://localhost/sss.php?'+seasoning);

  });

});

</script>
```

```html
<div>
<p>Select vegetables</p>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="vegetables[]" value="potato"> Potato</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="vegetables[]" value="onion"> Onion</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="vegetables[]" value="tomato"> Tomato</label><br>
</div>

<div>
<p>Select seasoning</p>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="seasoning[]" value="salt"> Salt</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="seasoning[]" value="pepper"> Pepper</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="seasoning[]" value="chilli"> Chilli Flakes</label><br>
</div>
```

but it run just in console
i can't fixed it to run in url 
 i want Append parameter to url

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are okay with your window refreshing, you have to do

Using `document.location.search += seasoning` makes the page refresh.

2. If you don't want window to refresh, you can use window.location [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method) or replaceState.

```
window.history.replaceState(null, null, 'http://localhost/sss.php?'+seasoning);
```

or

```
window.history.replaceState(null, null, 'http://localhost/sss.php?'+seasoning);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function (e) {
  var seasoning = '', tempArray = [];
  $('input[name="vegetables[]"]:checked').each(function(){
      tempArray.push($(this).val());
  })
  console.log(tempArray);
  if(tempArray.length !== 0){
     seasoning+='vegetables='+tempArray.toString();
     tempArray = [];
  }
  $('input[name="seasoning[]"]:checked').each(function(){
      tempArray.push($(this).val());
  });
  if(tempArray.length !== 0){
     seasoning+='&seasoning='+tempArray.toString();
  }
  console.log('http://localhost/sss.php?'+seasoning);
 });
});
```

```html
<div>
<p>Select vegetables</p>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="vegetables[]" value="potato"> Potato</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="vegetables[]" value="onion"> Onion</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="vegetables[]" value="tomato"> Tomato</label><br>
</div>

<div>
<p>Select seasoning</p>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="seasoning[]" value="salt"> Salt</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="seasoning[]" value="pepper"> Pepper</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="seasoning[]" value="chilli"> Chilli Flakes</label><br>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: there is an issue with this approach, first, it is not dynamic, and second when first select seasoning filter, it appends "?&seasoning=salt" in URL.